# Returning 0 and timestamp for SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B, 
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t_stamp)) AS Time
FROM 
    Log
WHERE 
    t_stamp BETWEEN '2018-03-01 06:00:00' AND '2018-04-06 06:00:00'
    AND Bad = 1
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t_stamp))
```

But it only returns values for days when A **or** B is not 0. As you can see below:

[image]

How do I modify this query to return 0 for A **AND** B columns with the corresponding timestamp? This is the output I'd like:

[image]

This database runs on Microsoft SQL Server and is being accessed using JDBC driver.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you don't have data on all the days where `bad = 1`.  One solution is `left join`, with either a calendar table or some other mechanism for generating all the days.

A more "hacky" solution often works.  If you have data on all days -- but just not bads -- then you can move the `where` condition to the `case`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'A' AND Bad = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bad_A, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'B' AND Bad = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bad_B, 
       CAST(t_stamp as DATE) AS Time
FROM Log l
WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN '2018-03-01 06:00:00' AND '2018-04-06 06:00:00'
GROUP BY CAST(t_stamp as DATE);
ORDER BY MIN(t_stamp);
```

Or, if `bad` only takes on the values of 0 and 1:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'A' THEN Bad ELSE 0 END) AS bad_A, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'B' THEN Bad ELSE 0 END) AS bad_B, 
       CAST(t_stamp as DATE) AS Time
FROM Log l
WHERE t_stamp BETWEEN '2018-03-01 06:00:00' AND '2018-04-06 06:00:00'
GROUP BY CAST(t_stamp as DATE);
ORDER BY MIN(t_stamp);
```

This doesn't work in all cases, but it is often the simplest solution to this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat hard to understand what you're doing without the schema, but does this give you what you want?

```
SELECT Time
FROM (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B, 
           dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, t_stamp)) as Time
    FROM Log
    WHERE t_stamp between '2018-03-01 06:00:00' AND '2018-04-06 06:00:00'
    AND Bad = 1
    GROUP BY dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, t_stamp))
) AS l
WHERE A = 1
    AND B = 1;
```

Comment: Hmm this query didn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Taking some assumptions here... and mocked up dumb data.  This what you're looking for?  (i think you just include the Side on your group by and you should pull the 0 side ones as well)

```
WITH Log AS
(
    SELECT
      Side = 'A', t_stamp = '2018-03-01 06:00:00', Bad = '1'
    UNION
    SELECT
      Side = 'B', t_stamp = '2018-03-01 06:00:00', Bad = '1'
    UNION
    SELECT
      Side = 'B', t_stamp = '2018-03-01 07:00:00', Bad = '1'
    UNION
    SELECT
      Side = ' ', t_stamp = '2018-03-01 06:00:00', Bad = '1'
)
SELECT A, B, Time
FROM
(
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS A, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN Side = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS B,
           dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, t_stamp)) as Time
    FROM Log
    WHERE t_stamp between '2018-03-01 06:00:00' AND '2018-04-06 06:00:00'
    AND Bad = 1
    GROUP BY Side, dateadd(DAY,0, datediff(day,0, t_stamp))
) a
```

Comment: This raises an error that says: "a result set was generated for update".

Comment: fiddle shows it running http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/24a9d/1  was this directly the code above or based on your datasource?  ..Or you caught me mid-edit heh